# Can I Use Google Maps Developer API to Get and/or Draw Regional Boundaries?

Tags: google-maps

If you look at the [Google maps website](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Al+Mohmmediah,+Jeddah,+Makkah+Province,+Saudi+Arabia&hl=en&ll=21.648813,39.128494&spn=0.29613,0.514641&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=63.343847,131.748047&oq=al+mohammediah,+jeddah,+s&hnear=Al+Mohmmediah,+Jeddah,+Makkah+Province+Saudi+Arabia&t=m&z=12), you can see that it accurately outlines a region (neigbourhood), giving you a pink shape that curves around the road. This means that Google has this data internally. If you use the [Google Maps Developer API](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DAl%20Mohmmediah%2C%20Jeddah%2C%20Makkah%20Province%26country%3DSA), however, it seems that you can only get a four-point boundaries object (NW, NE, SE, SW). If you then use this object to draw to, you basically get a rectangle.

Has anyone had this problem before and if so, how have you been able to get the detailed region info drawn on the map? Note that I'm trying to automate this as much as possible and I'm working in Saudi Arabia, where I don't think it's easy to get a third-party database of regional data.

Answer (score 0):

You can download free shapefiles from many countries for example from here: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata.